# Having a react native ios issue "apple match 0 linker error"

Tags: ios, react-native

I am generating a react native ios app using xcode but i am experiencing an issue "apple match 0 linker error". i have tried a lot of stuff to resolve this but i am getting any solution that work perfectly fine here is the screen shot attached please have a look on it.

[image]

Comment: the error is “File not found”. which file?

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk "Shopertino.app/Shopertino
clang" this is the file

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk i am not getting this issue and not getting this file as well